# Postgresql Trigger based on value of one column to change or update value of other column in each row.

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am a newbie student  in Postgresql.  I have only 4 columns  in students table

```
id              serial,
student_name    varchar(50), 
student_marks   integer,
grade           varchar(1)
```

Now I wish to create a trigger (Language : pl/sql) named `fill_grade_auto` so that depending on `student_marks`, the grade will be automatically updated as A (for above 90 marks) ,  B (for above 60 but less than 90) and rest with a C grade.

This trigger should be fired on every after insert or update on each row. I have tried different methods, but with no success.

Comment: Please include some code from your attempts

Comment: good question and good answer - why the hell it is closed??? it is really helpfull!

Comment: I've flagged for mod intervention to try to get this re-opened

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_grade() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.grade := CASE WHEN NEW.student_marks >= 90 THEN 'A' 
                    WHEN NEW.student_marks BETWEEN 60 AND 89 THEN 'B' 
                    ELSE 'C' END;

  RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_grade_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON students 
FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_grade();
```

**Note**: You may need to adjust boundaries for grades in `CASE`, because your question is a bit ambiguous on the subject. If read word for word a value of `90` doesn't belong to any grade. Therefore I took the liberty to interpret it my way (`A: 90<=marks, B: 60<= marks<90, c: marks<60`)

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a7bec/1)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Thank you so much peterm !!!  It only reminds me that I need to really put my efforts in learning pl/sql.

Comment: Thank you! Stupeditors close good questions

Comment: I was using `AFTER` instead of `BEFORE`, was baffled but this helped shine a light on the issue